# ionic2 and angular2 list element style depending on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a list like this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
      {{ user.name }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I want to add some style (for example a border around) to an element if it was clicked.

I am also want that only one item at a time can be "selcted" and be marked with that border.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using a property to hold the selected item; that way, only one item could be marked as selected. Please take a look at [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0z6ZjY?p=preview).

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class User {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html',
  styles: [`
    .active {
      background-color: antiquewhite;
    }
  `]
})
export class HomePage {

  public users: Array<User>;
  public selectedUser: User;

  constructor(public navController: NavController) {
    this.users = [];
    this.users.push(new User(1, 'User 1'));
    this.users.push(new User(2, 'User 2'));
    this.users.push(new User(3, 'User 3'));
    this.users.push(new User(4, 'User 4'));
    this.users.push(new User(5, 'User 5'));

    this.selectedUser = this.users[0];
  }

  public checkActiveUser(user: User): boolean {
    return user.id === this.selectedUser.id;
  }

  public selectUser(user: User): void {
    this.selectedUser = user;
  }

}
```

**View**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic App</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item (click)="selectUser(user)" [class.active]="checkActiveUser(user)" *ngFor="let user of users">
      {{ user.name }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

So basically we have a list of `users` (the one we use to create all the items) and we can also have a property in our component, named `selectedUser`, where we can assign the currently selected user (or the first user of the users list as default). We need that additional property to know which one we need to highlight. By using a single property, be can also allow only one user to be highlighted.

Once we have the list of `users` ready, and an `selectedUser` property (which is one of the users of the list), we just need to add a class to the item that represents the selected user. To do so, we add in the item:

```
[class.active]="checkActiveUser(user)"
```

the `checkActiveUser(...)` method receives an user and uses its id to check if that user is the same user of the `selectedUser` property. That way, the `active` class will be only added to the item that represents the user that we have selected.

The only thing left, is to add some styles to the `active` class to highlight that item.

Comment: Can you please explain more about your solution? This is exactly what I want but I don't understand what is going on :$

Comment: Np, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
<div class="leftContainer" [ngStyle]="{'width':item.selected?'50%':'100%'}"></div>
```

You can add **multiple css** by **comma separated**:

```
<div *ngIf="item.selected" class="rightContainer" [ngStyle]="{'height':sharedData.TabHeight-2 + 'px','width':reportModel.IsEditMode?'50%':'100%'}"></div>
```

**Note:** use your condition as per your requirement logic